# Android Google Maps v2 in Froyo (Android 2.2) not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hi i'm new in android and i'm implementing google maps v2 in my project and the minsdk version is 8 (2.2) when i run my project nothings wrong but when i click my button for gps always force close "java.lang.runtimeexception" and it keeps bothering me. could help me from this and thank you in advance. here is my codes.

LocationFinder.java

```
public class LocationFinder extends FragmentActivity {

private static final LatLng KOLKATA = new LatLng(22.5697, 88.3697);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_finder);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Marker kol = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(KOLKATA)
            .title("Kolkata").snippet("The City of Joy"));


    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(KOLKATA, 15));

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location_finder, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_location_finder.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LocationFinder" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mobeelity.android.mizootravel.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission              android:name="com.mobeelity.android.mizootravel.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZoomanityHome"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="HOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ServiDirect"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SERVICEDIRECTORY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.Zoocobia"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZOOCOBIA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZoocobiaGridViewLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZOOCOBIAGALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZPlanet"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZPLANET" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZPlanetGridViewLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZPLANETGALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ResidenceInn"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="RESIDENCEINN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ResidenceInnGridViewLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="RESIDENCEINNGALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.Paradizoo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="PARADIZOO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ParadizooGridViewLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="PARADIZOOGALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZoocolateThrills"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZOOCOLATETHRILLS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZoocolateThrillsGridViewLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZOOCOLATETHRILLSGALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZoobicSafari"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZOOBICSAFARI" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.ZoobicSafariGridViewLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ZOOBICSAFARIGALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.LocationFinder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="LOCATIONFINDER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobeelity.android.miizootravel.BookingInquiry"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="BOOKINGINQUIRY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA0TuMyQAOJrzywPvkTcuPZ9i7igbD9iFI" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are u using the emulator?

Comment: it would be helpful also if you post your logcat files.

Answer (score 0):

To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

- A compatible Android device that runs **Android 2.3 or higher** and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on **Android 4.2.2 or higher**.

More info: [**Set Up Google Play Services SDK**](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)